# Unhandled exception has occurred (when running installed application)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, installshield

I use installshield to compile an application which works fine during debugging, or when compiled and published using VS.

When I run the installed application I get the following error message:
[image: exception]

> See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
>   (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   path    at System.IO.File.AppendAllText(String path, String contents) 
>   at SerialPortListener.MainForm.MainForm_Load(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in
>   c:\Users\Jamie\Documents\SerialPortListener\SerialPortListener\MainForm.cs:line
>   291    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> ************** Loaded Assemblies ************** mscorlib
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- SerialPortListener
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/P%26L%20Software/P%26L%20Hardware%20Helper/SerialPortListener/obj/x86/Debug/SerialPortListener.exe
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34238 built by: FX452RTMGDR
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Configuration
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Xml
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34234 built by: FX452RTMGDR
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Accessibility
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
>
> ************** JIT Debugging ************** To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this application or computer
>   (machine.config) must have the jitDebugging value set in the
>   system.windows.forms section. The application must also be compiled
>   with debugging enabled.
>
> For example:
>
> When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception will be sent to
>   the JIT debugger registered on the computer rather than be handled by
>   this dialog box.

I have tried doing as it said and enabling jit debugging. That didn't work though. I can't seem to figure out the cause of this problem. I added some code at key points in the form to write the line number to a text file so I could see where it fails but it seems like the error occurs much before those logged messages. If I click continue the message keeps displaying, if I keep clicking, it seems as though it does slowly progress through the code but it takes many clicks of the same error.

Below is the MainForm_Load method:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(txtTerminal.Text);
    File.AppendAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorLog"],"Line:284" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code with the `path`variable.

Comment: @Sybren I have added this to my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generate a path in your `MainForm_Load` method in `MainForm`.

That fails and the result becomes `null`. At least that's what the exception says..

Comment: The only path I have there is the code to log the line number into a text file. I have added the code to my original question in case you can see anything obvious that's wrong.

Comment: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorLog"] is not specified in  the config that is distributed.

Comment: The key is included in the app.config, I also checked that it is both in the installshield files and in program files and it seems fine. It works fine when I run it any way other than as an installed program.

Comment: Well display it in a message box when running the app as installed. I still think it's missing then.

Comment: It seems you were right, I hard-coded the URL and it work seemed to work afterwards.